# How can i run specific vm using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, devops

I wrote infrastructure as code using terraform, and apply it successfully on azure cloud, now i created another 3 vm's using the same networking file and variable file that already used in the pervious IAAC, how can i run only these 3 vm's without generating new error, or "already exists" to create them on the same subscription and same variable/networking configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you understand correctly, you can use

```
terraform -target
```

Be notice that -target attribute respects dependencies